# FileNotFoundException when DNX Web App Published

Tags: dnx

I published a DNX app with the command:

```
dnu publish --runtime active --no-source -o ..\artifacts\bin\Release\2016-04-10-3
```

This created the output as expected with my code compiled into a DLL in the approot/packages folder.

The web.cmd file executes the below command at the end:

```
@"%DNX_PATH%" --project "%~dp0packages\MyProject\1.0.0\root" --configuration Release web %*
```

However, when I run it, I get the below exception:

```
Application startup exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MyProject' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

My initial thoughts are that the DNX command is missing the --packages param, but it throws an error when I add this. I'm not sure, what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

Thanks.
ARK

Comment: When I deploy this to another fresh machine, I get the same Exception, but this time for Kestrel. Again, this is in the packages folder, but DNX doesn't seem to be finding them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was due to me having a global.json and specific runtime in the project settings. Removed these and it worked.